# How does this def of factorial 0 return a 1

Tags: python, while-loop, function

I'm taking an intro python classes. Below is one of our problems where we had to create a procedure to find the factorial of a number. I don't understand when I enter the number 0, it returns the number 1.

If factorial(0) is entered, isn't anything multiplied by 0 going to be 0?  So, how does it produce the number 1 as the answer?

```
def factorial(n):
    result = 1
    while n >= 1:
        result = result * n
        n = n - 1
return result    

print factorial(0)
#>>> 1
```

Thank you,
Tom

Comment: `0 >= 1` is `False`. So the loop body is never executed. So no multiply by `0`.

Comment: Trace through it with pen and paper - you'll quickly find it!

Comment: Are you asking why the function returns that, or why mathematically 0! == 1? The first question falsetru answered. The second... isn't really appropriate here

Comment: asking why the function returns 1. But I think falsetru already answered it. Since the loop body is never executed and the result is initially defined as 1, the return result is 1.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it would be to add

```
if n == 0:
    result = 0
```

So the code would be

```
def factorial(n):
    result = 1
    if n == 0:
        result = 0
    while n >= 1:
         result = result * n
         n = n - 1
    return result    

print factorial(0)
```

Basically what was happening is that because zero is greater than one, the `while` loop never started and thus never changed `result`.  Because the default value of `result` was one, that is what was returned. Hope this helps.

EDIT: As pointed out to me by user "Haris" the factorial of zero is actually one.  However, if you are wondering why python produced that result, that is stated above.

Comment: Factorial of 0 is 1, not 0

Comment: My mistake, I never learned that in math.  Probably because it is not a common thing to need the factorial of 0. :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by falsetru:

0 >= 1 is False...so the loop body is never executed and the result is initially defined as 1, so the return result is 1.